# How to configure CKEditor to strip <script> tags from <head>?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, xss

I'm currently using the following code in a CKEditor 4.5.8 config file to strip `<svg>` and `<script>` tags from HTML content being edited in CKEditor.

```
config.allowedContent = {
    $1: {
        // Use the ability to specify elements as an object.
        elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
        attributes: true,
        styles: true,
        classes: true
    }
};

config.disallowedContent = 'svg;script;';
```

These tags are all stripped out just fine when they're included within `<body>`, but the tags all remain when they're included within `<head>`. I'm particularly worried about `<script>`s sticking around.

How should CKEditor be configured to strip `<script>` tags from `<head>`? Is there some deeper element of configuration I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add additional parameter when initializing CKEditor. This is necessary if you want to edit an entire HTML page, with `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` elements, you need to set the `config.fullPage` option to true:

```
config.allowedContent = {
    $1: {
        // Use the ability to specify elements as an object.
        elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
        attributes: true,
        styles: true,
        classes: true,
        fullPage: true
    }
};
```